# Timer in Python(simultany)

Tags: python, time

I have been looking for a timer to my project, but I only found timers that stop my code.

Does Python got an option to run a timer in a way that doesn't stop my other code?

Comment: when you're saying `timer`, do you mean a code that prints the ETA or something like that?

Comment: Probably you should use threads in order not to block main program execution. Here is a good tutorial. http://pymotw.com/2/threading/ And here is documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very easy but not so sophisticated way is to write:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
```

at the beginning of your code and at the end

```
print "run time (s):", time.time() - start_time
```

Note that in this solution the output time may be influenced by other processes running simultaniously on your computer. This is why this method is probably not the best.

A better solution would be "timeit":

https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

which can be used in very convenient fashion in ipython:

https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html

Last solution I know of, is to use a profiler (very nice in spyder for example):

http://sjara.github.io/spyder-profiler/

A profiler will tell you exactly how many times a function is used during the process and whats the total time spend in a function.